# Make a container "clear" a contained element's margin-top without overflow:hidden?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have an outer div and an inner div. I want the inner div to have 10px margin to the top end of the outer div.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        this one should have 10px margin top to the outer div!
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use `overflow:hidden` as I need to place some content outside the div. So what are the possibilities? I know I could use `border-top` or `padding-top`, but this seems a bit hacky to me. Isn't there any other way to tell the outer div to "respect" (clear? what's the correct word?) the margin of the inner div?

Here's the corresponding jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmuheim/C3eDa/

Comment: I'm not really understanding what the problem is - "I need to place some content outside the div." How is that preventing you from doing so? Can you provide an example of that..?

Comment: try it http://jsfiddle.net/crew1251/C3eDa/1/

Comment: As an alternative to margin-top for the inner div, you could just add padding-top to the outer div. Same effect.

Comment: I don't think there is a specific term for it, but the effect you're seeing is margin collapse and you're trying to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very well worded, so I answered the best I could. I'm assuming you want a space of 10px above and outside the inner div but inside the outer div. Thus I recommend to put padding at the top of the outer div. This will force 10px top margin on inner div no matter what.

```
.outer {
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C3eDa/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the margins of inner content using pseudo elements on the outer container.

Try:

```
/* clear margins of inner content */
.outer:before, .outer:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Updated the code a bit to simplify. I believe this solves your original question unless you had other requirements you forgot to mention.